# database disk image is malformed

Tags: sqlite

I got an error when trying to query an sqlite file in R saying `Error in rsqlite_fetch(res@ptr, n = n) : database disk image is malformed` likely indicating that the sqlite3 file is somehow malformed. Running `pragma integrity_check` returns `ok`.

The file size is 76GB. There is one table `main` containing 172 columns with an index.

This was meant to create an easier to access method for a series of unstructured files and so is intended only to be read only. I tried reconstituting it several times, but it always seems malformed.

Not sure what else to look at or to do. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: How about checking it from the Terminal, outside of R, to eliminate R as a potential problem? Or cooying the file to a different machine, with a potentially different version of sqlite to see if that works?

Comment: @MarkSetchell did that, same problem. It's definitely being sent by sqlite. But I didn't try a different version of sqlite - however, I tried creating other files of smaller size and it seems to work fine.

Comment: The file got corrupted. Restore it from the backup.

Comment: @CL I have a script building it from scratch and multiple attempts to reconstitute it have led to this - is there any way to determine how it was corrupted? When running on commandline, it returns several results from the request until returning "database disk image is malformed"

Comment: Are you saying that a sequence of valid SQL statements reliably results in a corrupted file? That would be a bug.

Comment: @CL I'm saying that a valid SQL SELECT statement resulted in the return of several results until outputting `database disk image is malformed`. From what I gather, this would mean if there was a corruption it would be further in the list list of entries, if that's possible (meaning not the entire file is corrupted if at all). I was wondering if there's any way of investigating that so I can figure out what I am doing wrong and what a possible solution could be. I am particularly confused about why the integrity check came back ok.

Comment: My issue, as it stands, is that whenever I try regenerating the table, I get the error, and I am unsure why.

Comment: Then what do you mean with "regenerating"? The SELECT?

Comment: Perhaps build and test in stages each building more or other parts. You could then get close to isolating the issue e.g. it might be a specific row that is causing the issue or it could be some other factor (e.g. space/memory)

Comment: @CL I have a bunch of flat files that I am reorganizing into sqlite format, which becomes malformed as a result. Smaller files seem to work fine, but larger ones seem to have this issue. I was hoping there was some way to hunt down the issue and I was hoping it wasn't the solution MikeT proposed.